# reodering the columns in a csv file + awk + keeping the comma delimiter

Tags: awk

this is my file:

```
$ cat temp
country,latitude,longitude,name,code
AU,-25.274398,133.775136,Australia,61
CN,35.86166,104.195397,China,86
DE,51.165691,10.451526,Germany,49
FR,46.227638,2.213749,France,33
NZ,-40.900557,174.885971,New Zealand,64
WS,-13.759029,-172.104629,Samoa,685
CH,46.818188,8.227512,Switzerland,41
US,37.09024,-95.712891,United States,1
VU,-15.376706,166.959158,Vanuatu,678
```

I want to reorder the columns like below. but I want to keep the comma delimiter and don't want the space delimiter. How do I do this?

```
$ awk -F"," '{ print $5,$4,$1,$2,$3 }' temp
code name country latitude longitude
61 Australia AU -25.274398 133.775136
86 China CN 35.86166 104.195397
49 Germany DE 51.165691 10.451526
33 France FR 46.227638 2.213749
64 New Zealand NZ -40.900557 174.885971
685 Samoa WS -13.759029 -172.104629
41 Switzerland CH 46.818188 8.227512
1 United States US 37.09024 -95.712891
678 Vanuatu VU -15.376706 166.959158
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`OFS` record](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-16) also needs to be set if you don't want the output field separator to be a space character (default).

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{ print $5,$4,$1,$2,$3 }' temp
code,name,country,latitude,longitude
61,Australia,AU,-25.274398,133.775136
86,China,CN,35.86166,104.195397
49,Germany,DE,51.165691,10.451526
33,France,FR,46.227638,2.213749
64,New Zealand,NZ,-40.900557,174.885971
685,Samoa,WS,-13.759029,-172.104629
41,Switzerland,CH,46.818188,8.227512
1,United States,US,37.09024,-95.712891
678,Vanuatu,VU,-15.376706,166.959158
```